# Jquery All Selector

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having problem in jquery all selectors.

I have three elements within my div, but when i use following lines of code to basically  give me the total length of my elements within my div tag although my div contains three elements but it is alerting out 0. Why ?

jquery code:

```
var element_count = $('#mydiv').find('*').length;
alert(element_count);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<p>Hi</p>
<span>Hello</span>
<h1>hey</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#mydiv').children().length;

Answer (score 3):

The reason that this code is not working is either its not executed or the DOM is not ready when the code is executed. Make sure you have wrapped the code in DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($('#mydiv').find('*').length);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jz7nc/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Wrap ur code in document.ready to make sure DOM is ready and then try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var element_count = $('#mydiv').children().length;
}
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/9aMSz/1/

As mentioned in jquery website http://api.jquery.com/children/ :-

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

another option is .find as shown in ur code but you are missing document.ready in your case!

Comment: +1 for using the better `children()` method, although I think the OPs problem is there is no DOMReady handler.

Comment: No! The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well

Comment: thanx @Reigel I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Reigel that's true, but OP has not clarified which he wants and his example only contains direct descendants. The implementation of `children()` will be much quicker than a contextual `*` selector.

Comment: thanks ... now it is working fine ... one another problem that i am facing is

<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>


$(iframe).load(function(){
 alert('Window loaded successfully');
})

..  actually i want that alert message to be displayed after, the iframe window has been loaded .. now here whether the DOM Is ready or not but it must alert out the message ... when the iframe window is loaded....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.children()` method to get a list of contained elements. You only get the **direct** children.

```
var contents = $("#myDiv").children();
var content_count = contents.length;
```